# Jenkins Pipeline: How may I define a variable inside a 'withGroovy' step?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to write a Jenkins pipeline that uses "System Groovy Script".  I have validated that the "Pipeline: Groovy" plugin has been installed.

When I try something simple like using 'println()', I have success.

```
pipeline
{
    agent { label 'remote' }
    
    stages
    {
        stage('sandbox')
        {
            steps
            {
                withGroovy
                {
                    println("Hello");                    
                    println("World");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do something more, like define a variable, the interpreter does not seem to recognize what I am doing.  As an example, if I add the following line to my code:

```
def content = "Hello World";
```

As follows:

```
pipeline
{
    agent { label 'remote' }
    
    stages
    {
        stage('sandbox')
        {
            steps
            {
                withGroovy
                {
                    println("Hello");
                    def content = "Hello World";
                    println("World");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I recieve this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 14: Expected a step @ line 14, column 21.
                       def content = "Hello World";
                       ^

1 error
```

Am I missing something?
Am I allowed to use standard Groovy code inside a 'withGroovy' step?

Answer (score 1):

Use `script` section instead of `withGroovy`. Actually saying that you want to use Groovy is quite strange as you already are in Groovy world. Just say "script".

You are now in declarative area, but you could consider scripted pipeline if you want to have more freedom by using rather code than declarations: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline